# Reference request: Hecke agebra over non-commutative rings

Tags: reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, hecke-algebras, noncommutative-rings

I think the title sums it up quite well: Is it a useful idea to define the Iwahori-Hecke algebra over a non-commutative $k$-algebra? If so, what shape should the relations attain?

Bonus question: what would be the appropriate definition of the $q$-commutator $[A, B]_q = AB-qBA$?